# Chart wont display values from Subreport return

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, return-value, subreport

I have a problem with a chart displaying values from a *subreport* that returns them. The chart simply wont show any data

Here is my image:

[image]

The chart evaluation time is set to "report". To make sure my returned values are valid i set up some quick text fields (those weird numbers on the right and left :P ) that are also set to "report" as evaluation time. They show the correct values, but my chart remains empty. Variable names are also correct!

I checked my chart functionality by providing static values or report values like "page_count" and that works. Only the returned subreport values make problems.

Any ideas?

Comment: Check the Subreport dataset connection and parameters in case if you are using.

Comment: but as you can see the values from the subreports returns correctly.. the numbers right and left are from the subreport. And those variables behind are used in the chart as well, and they dont show up.